# Prove that ${1\over x_1}+{1\over x_2}+\dots+{1\over x_n}\lt3$ if no $x_j=10^kx_i+n$ where $x_i,k,n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ and $x_i\not=x_j$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that ${1\over x_1}+{1\over x_2}+\dots+{1\over x_n}\lt3$ if no $x_j=10^kx_i+n$ where $x_i,k,n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, $n<10$, and $x_i\not=x_j$

I have attempted this question multiple times and have barely reached anything. I tried to assume WLOG that $x_1\le x_2\le\dots\le x_n$ however I could not continue. I am still new to such inequality questions so any help would be appreciated. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Suppose $n=4$ and $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=1$.  Then it is certainly true that no $x_j=10^kx_i+4$  but $\sum \frac 1{x_i}=4$.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: I forgot to add that they are distinct

Comment: And are they meant to be positive integers?  Please edit your post to include all the conditions you have in mind.

Comment: Ok.  Taking  $n=11$ and $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(1,2,3,\cdots, 11)$ then again it is clearly true that no $x_j=10^kx_i+11$ and $\sum \frac 1{x_i}=3.019877345>3$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated this is false:

Taking  $n=11$ and $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(1,2,3,\cdots, 11)$ then  it is clearly true that no $x_j=10^kx_i+11$ (for $k\in \mathbb Z^+$) and $$\sum_{i=1}^{11} \frac 1{i}=3.019877345>3$$

Comment: forgot to write that $n<10$

Comment: It's hard to answer questions when the terms keep changing.  This new rule can't be right, since $\sum_{i=1}^{9}\frac 1i=2.828968254<3$.

Comment: im sorry, hopefully now all the terms are right.

Comment: As I say, with $n<10$ the problem is trivial, since $\sum_{i=1}^9\frac 19<3$.

Comment: At this point, I'm guessing that you incorrectly used the variable $n$ to mean two different things...you use it as the number of the $x_i$ and you use it as the "remainder" in the $x_j=10^kx_i+n$ expression.